# Deterministic Prime Construction

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding a prime greater than a given bound](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4882/finding-a-prime-greater-than-a-given-bound)

### Question

Does there exist

- a polynomial $q$
- and a deterministic polynomial time algorithm $A$

  such that for all sufficiently large $n$, we have:

  $A(n)$ outputs a prime $p$ s.t. $n \leq p \leq q(n)$. (Note $n$ is stored in binary, so $A$ must run in $poly(\log n)$ time.)

### Context

Suppose that for some derandomization task we need to be able to construct primes. This rules out the "guess a random number + check" approach since we can't use randomness.

### Known

- We have deterministic construction of irreducible polynomials: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S074771718471025X
- We also have deterministic primality checking: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test
- By http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_postulate there is a prime between $n$ and $2n-2$, but we can't check all $n$ numbers in $poly(\log n)$ time.
- By http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem we know that $\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\ln x}$, but it's not clear that this implies there is a prime between $n$ and $n+O(\log n)$.

Comment: AFAIR, it is open if that is possible.

Comment: @Kaveh: You're right, this is an exact duplicate. Should I delete this question or wait for it to be closed?

Comment: Closed as a duplicate.