# Find next prime

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

What's the best known complexity for the following problem? Given a number $n$, return the smallest prime larger than $n$.

Clearly one can just test all the odd numbers large than $n$ in turn until you find one. You can use a probabilistic primality testing algorithm with one-sided error and then confirm any primes using a AKS if needs be. This is slow but uses small space. Alternatively one could us a sieve which will be faster but uses potentially very large space.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding a prime greater than a given bound](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4882/finding-a-prime-greater-than-a-given-bound)

Comment: The linked question seems to insist the algorithm is deterministic and also answers a different question. I am looking for the next prime, not any prime greater than $n$.

Comment: I thought that you were looking for a deterministic algorithm, but I was wrong, as was apparent from your example.  I agree that it is a different question from the linked one; at least I do not know how to reduce one to the other in either direction.  My apologies.

Answer (score 7):

Heuristically there is a prime between $n$ and $n + log^2 n$ for any 
sufficiently large $n$, so yes there is a deterministic polynomial time algorithm,
which  works quite well in practice (but is heuristic).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap

I do not think that there  is a known algorithm with provable polynomial time algorithm for this problem. The best provable complexity you can achieve
is $ n^{0.525} $.

Comment: QiCheng how do you achieve $n^{0.525}$?

Comment: $n^{0.525}$ is polynomial in $n$, but this is exponential in the size of the input, which is $\log n$.

Comment: Well, it is known that between $n$ and $n + n^{0.525}$ there must be a prime

Comment: OK, but if we include lower-order stuff, more specifically with AKS this gives about $n^{0.525} \log^6 n$; that is, $b^6 2^{0.525b}$ on $b$-bit input. Unless there is an asymptotic improvement in which numbers you check?

Comment: In computational number theory, it is convention to use \tilde{O} for complexity. The "\log^6 n" disappear if you use \tilde{O}. In fact, the AKS time complexity of \log^6 n is also for \tilde{O}.